# Reassigning Variables via Destructuring

Tags: kotlin

I love Kotlin's destructuring features, they help me to declutter code and focus on the essential.

I encountered a case for which I could not figure out the correct syntax, how can I reassign variables via destructing?

```
var (start, end) = startEndDate(198502)

// intellij neither accept this ...
start, end = startEndDate(200137)

// ... nor this
(start, end) = startEndDate(200137)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the language perspective, the variables declared in destructuring declaration are just separate independent variables, and at the moment Kotlin doesn't provide a way to assign multiple variables in a single statement.

You can only destructure your expression again and assign the variables one by one:

```
var (start, end) = startEndDate(198502)

val (newStart, newEnd) = startEndDate(200137)
start = newStart
end = newEnd
```

---

If you need to show that these two variables have have some special meaning and should be assigned together, you can declare a local function that reassigns them like this:

```
var (start, end) = startEndDate(198502)
fun setStartEnd(pair: Pair<SomeType, SomeType>) { start = pair.first; end = pair.second }

setStartEnd(startEndDate(200137))
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `with`: `with(startEndDate(200137)) { start = first; end = second }`.

Comment: @mfulton26 : can you elaborate `with`? how can we use with here as alternative?

Comment: @Kushal, if you have some variables that you assigned via destructing and want to reassign them then you can use `with` to more easily reassign them. e.g. `with(startEndDate(200137)) { start = first; end = second }` instead of `var tmpDate = startEndDate(200137); start = tmpDate.first; end = tmpDate.second`, `var tmpDate = startEndDate(200137); start = tmpDate.startDate; end = tmpDate.endDate`, etc. (depending on the return type of `startEndDate`).

Comment: Vote on the issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11362)